# Google Sheets - Script changing A1 to A2 to A3, ... inside a formula

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to do something basic on a google spreadsheet but I have no coding experience. I've tried searching for similar scripts but I'm not sure what to look for.

I have 2 sheets :

• `Questions` is a long list of questions (in column A) with answers (in column B). This sheet will be hidden in the future.

• `Quiz` is where a question and its answer (from the `Questions` sheet) show up.

---

I would like a "next" button which changes the current question and answer to the followings. On the `Quiz` sheet, I have a formula `=Questions!A1` which shows question1 and `=Questions!B1` which shows answer1.

I already know how to assign a script to a button so that's ok. What I need is a script that changes the formula from `=Questions!A1` to `=Questions!A2` to `=Questions!A3` and so on each time I click.

Same for the answers: from `=Questions!B1` to `=Questions!B2` to `=Questions!B3` and so on.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can do this by incrementing the R1C1 notation of the formula.*

#### Code:

```
// Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

function onButtonClick() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  let r = s.getRange('A2:B2')
  let f = r.getFormulasR1C1();
  var n = [];

  f.forEach(function(c) {
    let row = (parseInt(c[0].match(/R\[([0-9]*)\]/)[1]) + 1);
    n.push(["=Questions!R[" + row + "]C[0]"])
  });
  r.setFormulaR1C1(n)
}
```

**Rundown of this script:**

- Gets the range of the Question and Answer from the 'Quiz' Sheet (in this example it has been assumed to be `A2:B2`)
- Gets the formulae in these cells as `R1C1` notation
- Uses the regular expression `/R\[([0-9]*)\]/` to get the current increment of the row

  - Increments this number by 1
- Creates a new array of formulae to save to `A2:B2`
- Sets the formulae.

#### References:

- [Regular expression - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)
- [Class Range - getFormulasR1C1() | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformulasr1c1)

Answer (score 0):

Use a script like this when you click the button

```
var range = sheet.getRange("A1").setFormula("=Questions!A2");
```

Comment: This will only work the first time and not incrementally.